# Question about subsequential limits and limit superiors

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the question: Given a sequence $s_n = \left(1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4} \ldots \right)$, find the set of subsequential limits and lim sup $s_n$ and lim inf $s_n$.

Here's my solution. Can someone please verify it?

The set of all subsequential limits is $S = \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

lim sup $s_n = 1$

lim inf $s_n = 0$

Comment: Zero is also a the limit of a subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

(set of all subsequential limits) $S = \{0,1 \}$

lim sup $s_n = 1$

lim inf $s_n = 0$